# Loading data to datatable using AJAX on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using datatables to load data to table on clicking on elements in D3 charts. I have the following code for initializing the table :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Table = $('#data-table').DataTable({
        data: [],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "error_code" },
            { "data": "message" }
        ]
    });
});
```

Now  I have another click function as follows :

```
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        data: { code: node.data.name },
        url: "get_table_data"
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        Table.clear().draw();
        Table.rows.add(data);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });
```

I am getting data from server and it is logged to console in the correct format. But the data is not loaded to the table. It is showing `No data available in table`.

PS: Table initialization and the code to load data using ajax are in two javascript files.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the examples [in the DataTable documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()) you should redraw the table after adding the data:

```
...
}).done(function (data) {
        Table.clear().rows.add(data).draw();
}).fail(...)
...
```